# DDEV on VMware Ubuntu 18 VM

Tags: ddev

ddev will not start on VMware Ubuntu 18 VM and fails.

fails with the following error messages.

> Failed to start drupaltraining: ddev-router failed to become ready:
>   logOutput=nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax
>   is ok
>       nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
>       nginx config: OK  ddev-router healthcheck endpoint not responding
>         % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                        Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>         0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
>       , err=container /ddev-router unhealthy: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>       nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
>       nginx config: OK  ddev-router healthcheck endpoint not responding
>         % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                        Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>         0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused

I was able to get it working on a physical Ubuntu 18 box.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You had already created this as an issue, https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1826, so followup will be there.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and reaf [ask], then improve your question (edit)!